# Cannot Access C# Variable outside of foreach Loop

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I currently am developing a SharePoint Web part that will populate some stuff based of the of the List. Everything is working as expected but I can't seem to access the variable that has all the list items!

The Variable I want to access is `theValue1`.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace SPListWebPart.VisualWebPart1 {
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string theValue1;
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://maindt/sites/dev");
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList list = web.Lists["Links"];

            foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items) {
                theValue1 = item["URL"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your design is, but `theValue1` is a string, not a list, and its value gets overwritten on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

To get around the error message, you just need to provide a default value:

```
string theValue1 = string.Empty;
```

That being said, your current code will just set `theValue1` to the *last* URL in `list.Items`, so your loop could be rewritten as:

```
theValue1 = list.Items.Last()["URL"].ToString();
```

If you want the string to represent *all* of the items, you might want to consider using something like:

```
theValue1 = string.Join(", ", list.Items.Select(item => item["URL"].ToString()));
```

If you want to store a `List<string>` of all of the URLs, you could use:

```
List<string> theValues = list.Items.Select(i => i["URL"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a default value for it, else what happens if there's no items?

**Also,** your current code just gets the last value and puts it in the string. If you want all the values use this:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theValue1 = list.Items.Last()["URL"].ToString();
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://maindt/sites/dev");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList list = web.Lists["Links"];
}
```

However, if you want all the values you're looking for an `Enumerable` and `Select`:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<string> theValues1 = list.Items.Select(i => i["URL"].ToString());
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://maindt/sites/dev");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList list = web.Lists["Links"];
}
```

Comment: Also you should be using a using block as SPsite and SPweb will not be disposed of correctly

Answer (score 0):

- You are overwriting the `theValue1` in each iteration of your loop.
- If you want to access your variable somewhere else, put it outside of the `Page_Load` function